# Normal distribution inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, and $N(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x n(t)dt$. Prove the following inequality.
$$(x^2+1)N + xn-(xN+n)^2>N^2$$
where the dependency of $n$ and $N$ on $x$ are absorbed into the function symbols.

The left hand side is actually the variance of a truncated normal distribution. I am trying to give it a lower bound.

Comment: How comes you choose $N^2$ as a possible lower bound?

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou: Because it is below the left hand side on the plot of both sides. As a matter of fact, $N$ is the upper bound and I have proved it.